# meta viewport doesn´t work to zoom out

Tags: zooming, viewport, meta

I have a responsive web, but I want to allow the user to zoom out on this screen:
http://regalauncuento.es/comprar-cuento-infantil?aid=186

Please, open this link in your mobile device, you can check that zoom in works fine, but the zoom out is disabled...

I use this meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I try this too, but zoom out continues fail:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

What is happening here?, thanks you.